# Name "open_img" isn't defined tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am getting the error in the open_img when I try to run it. I am making an Emotion detector. I want to upload an image in tkinter. That's what my code is about.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Here is my script, my environment, the error traceback, and what have investigated so far.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.title("Emotion Detector")
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 1200, height = 700, bg='blue')
canvas1.pack()
root.resizable(width=True, height=True)
btn = Button(root, text='open image', command=open_img).grid(row=1,columnspan=4)
root.mainloop

def openfn():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='open')
    return filename

def open_img():
    x = openfn()
    img = Image.open(x)
    img = img.resize((250, 250), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    print(img)
    panel = Label(root, image=img)
    panel.image = img
    panel.grid(row=2)
```

My  error is attached below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hiler/Desktop/Internship/Frontend Python Final.py", line 11, in <module>
    btn = Button(root, text='open image', command=open_img).grid(row=1,columnspan=4)
NameError: name 'open_img' is not defined
```

I have seen an error of the same name here, but that appears to be a separate issue. So, I don't understand what to rectify in the code.
I am using IDLE python 3.9.7

Comment: You need to move the function definition of `open_img` to before the problem line.

Comment: Note also that you have missing `()` on the line `root.mainloop`.  Code beyond `mainloop()` will not be executed until the root window is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

move the function at the begin of the file. you are also missing () in
root.mainloop
change into **root.mainloop()**